# Loading a file with the LoadFromFile () function with a newline

Tags: c++, c++builder

I load the text file `.txt` using the `LoadFromFile()` function, and the text in the middle of the line is marked with a newline `'\n'`.
The `LoadFromFile()` function treats this character as a new line and divides the line in that place by creating a new line.
In the Windows system Note the text looks like this: `**Ala has ace**`
The program that loads this file looks different:

```
plik->LoadFromFile( path,  TEncoding::ASCII);

for( short int i = 0; i < plik->Count; ++i )
   Memo1->Lines->Add( plik->Strings[i] );
```

In Memo1 the text looks like this:

```
**Ala**

**has ace**
```

Can I remove the `'\n'` character to make the entire line and how?

Comment: What the missing "an" word has to do with '\n' character? '\n' is end-of-line so how it can be in the middle of the line I do not understand.

Comment: Yes, I used function Pos() to find position of the sign \n but result is 0. So I don't know if there is this new line

Comment: It is not clear if the file contains an escape sequence composed of 2 consecutive '\' and 'n' or if it contains a newline char '\n' (i.e. 0x0A).  It's also not clear if you want to remove the newline from the input, or only for the display.  COuld you clarify please ?

Comment: I want to remove this newline from the input

Answer (score 0):

I answered this same question on the [Embarcadero forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=255416) earlier today, but I will answer it here, too.

`plik` is a `TStringList` (according to the other discussion), so its `LoadFrom...()` method treats bare-CR, bare-LF, and CRLF line breaks equally when the `TStrings::LineBreak` property matches the RTL's global `sLineBreak` constant. If the `LineBreak` property does not match `sLineBreak`, then `TStrings` only splits on line breaks that match its `LineBreak` property.

Since the RTL's `sLineBreak` constant is CRLF on Windows, and you don't
want to split on bare-LF line breaks, you are going to have to parse
the file data manually, not use `TStrings::LoadFromFile()` at all.

For instance, you could read the whole file into a `System::String` using the [`System::Classes::TStreamReader::ReadToEnd()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStreamReader.ReadToEnd) or [`System::Ioutils::TFile::ReadAllText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText) method (`TStreamReader` and `TFile` both have methods for reading lines, but they both treat all three forms of line break equally), and then parse that `String` to extract CRLF-delimited substrings while ignoring any bare-LF characters.

Ideally, you would load a file into a `TMemo` by using its own `LoadFromFile()` method.  But, in this situation, that will not work, either, because `TMemo` normalizes all three forms of line breaks to CRLF before passing the data to the Win32 API, so that is not useful to you.